When my document is loaded, I need the deferredPrompt.prompt() to get the alert install prompt without clicking any button
I need my PWA app to get download without clicking any buttons.
I tried using onload event, in which I tried with this code which doesn't getting triggered
window.addEventListener("beforeinstallprompt", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    deferredPrompt = e;
});


Not relevant question for stackoverflow
